# R: recursively evaluating a binary tree stored as a list

Tags: r, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I have a tree called `mytree` that looks like this:

[image]

I have it stored as a list:

```
mytree <- list(list(structure(list(y = c(-10, 7, 8, -7), x = c(10, 20, 
25, 35), grad = c(-10.5, 6.5, 7.5, -7.5), sim_score = c(4, 4, 
4, 4), value = c(-1, -1, -1, -1)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")), 
    list(structure(list(y = -10, x = 10, grad = -10.5, sim_score = 110.25, 
        value = -10.5, gain = 120.333333333333, criterion = "x < 15"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
        structure(list(y = c(7, 8, -7), x = c(20, 25, 35), grad = c(6.5, 
        7.5, -7.5), sim_score = c(14.0833333333333, 14.0833333333333, 
        14.0833333333333), value = c(2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 
        2.16666666666667), gain = c(120.333333333333, 120.333333333333, 
        120.333333333333), criterion = c("x >= 15", "x >= 15", 
        "x >= 15")), row.names = 2:4, class = "data.frame")), 
    list(NULL, NULL, structure(list(y = c(7, 8), x = c(20, 25
    ), grad = c(6.5, 7.5), sim_score = c(98, 98), value = c(7, 
    7), gain = c(140.166666666667, 140.166666666667), criterion = c("x < 30", 
    "x < 30")), row.names = 2:3, class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        y = -7, x = 35, grad = -7.5, sim_score = 56.25, value = -7.5, 
        gain = 140.166666666667, criterion = "x >= 30"), row.names = 4L, class = "data.frame")), 
    list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, structure(list(y = 7, x = 20, 
        grad = 6.5, sim_score = 42.25, value = 6.5, gain = 0.5, 
        criterion = "x < 22.5"), row.names = 2L, class = "data.frame"), 
        structure(list(y = 8, x = 25, grad = 7.5, sim_score = 56.25, 
            value = 7.5, gain = 0.5, criterion = "x >= 22.5"), row.names = 3L, class = "data.frame"), 
        NULL, NULL))
```

and it looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
    y  x  grad sim_score value
1 -10 10 -10.5         4    -1
2   7 20   6.5         4    -1
3   8 25   7.5         4    -1
4  -7 35  -7.5         4    -1


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
    y  x  grad sim_score value     gain criterion
1 -10 10 -10.5    110.25 -10.5 120.3333    x < 15

[[2]][[2]]
   y  x grad sim_score    value     gain criterion
2  7 20  6.5  14.08333 2.166667 120.3333   x >= 15
3  8 25  7.5  14.08333 2.166667 120.3333   x >= 15
4 -7 35 -7.5  14.08333 2.166667 120.3333   x >= 15


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
NULL

[[3]][[2]]
NULL

[[3]][[3]]
  y  x grad sim_score value     gain criterion
2 7 20  6.5        98     7 140.1667    x < 30
3 8 25  7.5        98     7 140.1667    x < 30

[[3]][[4]]
   y  x grad sim_score value     gain criterion
4 -7 35 -7.5     56.25  -7.5 140.1667   x >= 30


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
NULL

[[4]][[2]]
NULL

[[4]][[3]]
NULL

[[4]][[4]]
NULL

[[4]][[5]]
  y  x grad sim_score value gain criterion
2 7 20  6.5     42.25   6.5  0.5  x < 22.5

[[4]][[6]]
  y  x grad sim_score value gain criterion
3 8 25  7.5     56.25   7.5  0.5 x >= 22.5

[[4]][[7]]
NULL

[[4]][[8]]
NULL
```

The first index of the list, i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, correspond to the level, or height of the tree. The second index corresponds to the index of the node in the given level. For example, `mytree[[1]][[1]]` contains the root, which has child nodes in `mytree[[2]][[1]]` and `mytree[[2]][[2]]`.

Given a parent node stored in `mytree[[i]][[j]]`, its children are stored in `mytree[[i + 1]][[2 * j]]` and `mytree[[i + 1]][[2 * j -1]]`.

I want to write a function called `eval_tree` that when given a new instance `x`, it will check which leaf node `x` falls into by checking the `criterion` of the splits and then output the value of the leaf, which is stored under `value`. Here is an example of how I'd like `eval_tree` to work:

```
newdata <- data.frame(x = c(10, 20, 25, 35))
> eval_tree(tree = mytree, newdata = newdata)
[1] -10.5
[2] 6.5
[3] 7.5
[4] -7.5
```

Here is what I have so far. Unfortunately it's not working...and I think I may need to implement the function recursively so that it's more efficient. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
eval_tree <- function(tree, newdata){
  if(length(tree) == 1){
    # If tree only has a root, return value of root
    return(tree[[1]][[1]]$value[1])
  }else if(length(tree) > 1){
    for (level in 2:length(tree)){
      for(ind in 1:length(tree[[level]]))
        if(eval(parse(text = tree[[level]][[ind]][["criterion"]]))){
          # Criterion is true, then go to child node
          # Check if there is child node
          if(is.null(tree[[level + 1]][[ind * 2]]) && is.null(tree[[level + 1]][[ind * 2 - 1]])){
            return(tree[[level]][[ind]]$value[1])
          }else if(eval(parse(text = tree[[level + 1]][[ind * 2]][["criterion"]]))){
            # Criterion is true, then go to childi node
            # I think this is where recursion would be more appropriate than all these nested loops
          }

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `partykit` for similarity and inspiration? https://cran.r-project.org/package=partykit

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with that package. Is there a specific function that you think would be helpful?

Comment: You just changed the structure of the tree completely. Now here recursion will not work as the depth of the tree is fixed. I am quite unsure why you did so. Will have to look at this from a different angle rather than recursion. With a tree, we talk of depth. How deep each branch goes. Hence I think your first structure was correct.

Comment: @Onyambu. So you're suggesting that recursion does not work with this structure with fixed depth? Can't I check whether the current node has any child nodes? If not, I'll return the current `value`. Otherwise, keep recursively checking whether the child node's `criterion` is met? Is this the correct line of thought?

Comment: @YQW. as long as one understands how they keep the data, it is fine. Just took sometime and saw that even this can work. I just need to wrap my mind around it

Comment: @Onyambu thank you for all of your help. I will keep thinking about this too.. I'm a bit new to this so I'm not the quickest when it comes to coding recursively in R

Comment: try the solution i gave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
index <- function(x,tree,e, i = 1, j = 1)
{
  if(nrow((tree[[i]][[j]])) == 1)
  {
    if(eval(parse(text=tree[[i]][[j]]$crite), list(x = x))) {
      if(is.null(e$a)){
        e$a <- i
        e$b <- tree[[i]][[j]]$val
      }
      else if(e$a > i)e$b <- tree[[i]][[j]]$val
      TRUE
    }
    else FALSE
  }
  else index(x, tree, e,i + 1,2*j-1) | index(x, tree,e,i+1, 2*j)
}

pred_tree <- function( tree,newdata){

 cbind(newdata,pred = sapply(newdata$x,function(x){
   e <- new.env()
   index(x,tree,e)
    e$b
   }))
}

pred_tree(mytree,data.frame(x = c(10,20,25,30,25)))
   x  pred
1 10 -10.5
2 20   6.5
3 25   7.5
4 30  -7.5
5 25   7.5
```